# How to change the font size in the packing slip PDF

Tags: pdf, print, magento-1.3, packing-slip

I am running on version 1.3

The font on the Packing Slip PDF is very small and I would like to increase the size. I suspect when I do so the formatting will go wrong so can anyone tell me how change the font size and keep a nice looking layout?

Answer (score 2):

You need to go on below class and override in local module then update size in setFontRegular method.

Firstly, copy `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`to prevent overwrites during security upgrades.

Then edit:

```
protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 10)
{

$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}
```